# Converting lat/long coordinates to UTM using JavaScript - wrong easting

Tags: coordinate-system, javascript, coordinates

I am trying to convert these coordinates to UTM

```
const longitude = 143.5279742;
const latitude = 44.062027;


// Calculate the UTM coordinates
const zoneNumber = Math.floor((longitude + 180) / 6) + 1;

const k = 0.9996;
const e = 0.081819190842965;
const e2 = e * e;
const e4 = e2 * e2;
const e6 = e4 * e2;
const N = 6378137 / Math.sqrt(1 - e2 * Math.pow(Math.sin(latitude * Math.PI / 180), 2));
const T = Math.pow(Math.tan(latitude * Math.PI / 180), 2);
const C = e4 * Math.pow(Math.cos(latitude * Math.PI / 180), 2);
const A = (longitude - ((zoneNumber - 1) * 6 - 180 + 3)) * Math.PI / 180;
const M = 6378137 * ((1 - e2 / 4 - 3 * e4 / 64 - 5 * e6 / 256) * latitude * Math.PI / 180 
                   - (3 * e2 / 8 + 3 * e4 / 32 + 45 * e6 / 1024) * Math.sin(2 * latitude * Math.PI / 180)
                   + (15 * e4 / 256 + 45 * e6 / 1024) * Math.sin(4 * latitude * Math.PI / 180)
                   - (35 * e6 / 3072) * Math.sin(6 * latitude * Math.PI / 180));

const A_prime = A - (1 - T + C) * Math.pow(A, 3) / 6 + (5 - 18 * T + Math.pow(T, 2) + 72 * C - 58 * e2) * Math.pow(A, 5) / 120;

const x = k * N * (A_prime * 180 / Math.PI + 0.9996 * 500000 + 0.5);
const y = k * (M + N * Math.tan(latitude * Math.PI / 180) * (Math.pow(A_prime, 2) / 2 + (5 - T + 9 * C + 4 * C * C) * Math.pow(A_prime, 4) / 24 + (61 - 58 * T + Math.pow(T, 2) + 600 * C - 330 * e2) * Math.pow(A_prime, 6) / 720));

// Format the output as a string
const utmString = zoneNumber + " " + Math.round(x) + " " + Math.round(y);



text_UTM.setValue(utmString);
```

> Blockquote

The northing produced and zone are correct however the easting is wrong. it should produce the easting 702469.05 but the number is completely wrong. Any advice?

Comment: I think your x equation is incorrect. The scale factor ("k") is applied before the false easting is added. It looks like you're applying it twice. The false easting definitely shouldn't be multiplied by the scale factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/utm-latlng it has already the formulas for the conversion

```
utm.convertLatLngToUtm(44.062027, 143.5279742, 1);
```

I haven't found a CDN of this, this is the file used: https://github.com/shahid28/utm-latlng/blob/master/UTMLatLngFront.js

Result:

```
{"Easting":702469,"Northing":4881869,"ZoneNumber":54,"ZoneLetter":"T"}
```

/*********************/
/** start copied from https://github.com/shahid28/utm-latlng/blob/master/UTMLatLngFront.js **/
/*********************/
/*********************/
/*********************/

```
var datumName = "WGS 84";
var a;
var eccSquared;
var status = false;

function UTMLatLng (datumNameIn){

  if (datumNameIn !== undefined)
  {
      datumName = datumNameIn;
  }
  this.setEllipsoid(datumName);
}

UTMLatLng.prototype.convertLatLngToUtm = function (latitude, longitude,precision){
    if (this.status)
    {
        return 'No ecclipsoid data associated with unknown datum: ' + datumName;
    }


    if(!Number.isInteger(precision))
    {
        return 'Precision is not integer number.';
    }

    latitude = parseFloat(latitude);
    longitude = parseFloat(longitude);

    var LongTemp = longitude;
    var LatRad = this.toRadians(latitude);
    var LongRad = this.toRadians(LongTemp);

    if (LongTemp >= 8 && LongTemp <= 13 && latitude > 54.5 && latitude < 58) {
        ZoneNumber = 32;
    } else if (latitude >= 56.0 && latitude < 64.0 && LongTemp >= 3.0 && LongTemp < 12.0) {
        ZoneNumber = 32;
    } else {
        ZoneNumber = ((LongTemp + 180) / 6) + 1;

        if (latitude >= 72.0 && latitude < 84.0) {
            if (LongTemp >= 0.0 && LongTemp < 9.0) {
                ZoneNumber = 31;
            } else if (LongTemp >= 9.0 && LongTemp < 21.0) {
                ZoneNumber = 33;
            } else if (LongTemp >= 21.0 && LongTemp < 33.0) {
                ZoneNumber = 35;
            } else if (LongTemp >= 33.0 && LongTemp < 42.0) {
                ZoneNumber = 37;
            }
        }
    }
    ZoneNumber = parseInt(ZoneNumber);

    var LongOrigin = (ZoneNumber - 1) * 6 - 180 + 3;  //+3 puts origin in middle of zone
    var LongOriginRad = this.toRadians(LongOrigin);

    var UTMZone = this.getUtmLetterDesignator(latitude);

    var eccPrimeSquared = (this.eccSquared) / (1 - this.eccSquared);

    var N = this.a / Math.sqrt(1 - this.eccSquared * Math.sin(LatRad) * Math.sin(LatRad));
    var T = Math.tan(LatRad) * Math.tan(LatRad);
    var C = eccPrimeSquared * Math.cos(LatRad) * Math.cos(LatRad);
    var A = Math.cos(LatRad) * (LongRad - LongOriginRad);

    var M = this.a * ((1 - this.eccSquared / 4 - 3 * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared / 64 - 5 * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared / 256) * LatRad
            - (3 * this.eccSquared / 8 + 3 * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared / 32 + 45 * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared / 1024) * Math.sin(2 * LatRad)
            + (15 * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared / 256 + 45 * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared / 1024) * Math.sin(4 * LatRad)
            - (35 * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared / 3072) * Math.sin(6 * LatRad));

    var UTMEasting = parseFloat(0.9996 * N * (A + (1 - T + C) * A * A * A / 6
            + (5 - 18 * T + T * T + 72 * C - 58 * eccPrimeSquared) * A * A * A * A * A / 120)
            + 500000.0);

    var UTMNorthing = parseFloat(0.9996 * (M + N * Math.tan(LatRad) * (A * A / 2 + (5 - T + 9 * C + 4 * C * C) * A * A * A * A / 24
            + (61 - 58 * T + T * T + 600 * C - 330 * eccPrimeSquared) * A * A * A * A * A * A / 720)));

    if (latitude < 0)
        UTMNorthing += 10000000.0;
    UTMNorthing = parseInt(Math.round(UTMNorthing));
    UTMEasting = parseInt(Math.round(UTMEasting));
    return {Easting: UTMEasting, Northing: UTMNorthing, ZoneNumber: parseInt(ZoneNumber), ZoneLetter: UTMZone};


};

UTMLatLng.prototype.convertUtmToLatLng = function (UTMEasting, UTMNorthing, UTMZoneNumber, UTMZoneLetter){
    var e1 = (1 - Math.sqrt(1 - this.eccSquared)) / (1 + Math.sqrt(1 - this.eccSquared));
    var x = UTMEasting - 500000.0; //remove 500,000 meter offset for longitude
    var y = UTMNorthing;
    var ZoneNumber = UTMZoneNumber;
    var ZoneLetter = UTMZoneLetter;
    var NorthernHemisphere;
    if(UTMEasting===undefined)
    {
        return "Please pass the UTMEasting!";
    }
    if(UTMNorthing===undefined)
    {
        return "Please pass the UTMNorthing!";
    }
    if(UTMZoneNumber===undefined)
    {
        return "Please pass the UTMZoneNumber!";
    }
    if(UTMZoneLetter===undefined)
    {
        return "Please pass the UTMZoneLetter!";
    }

    if ('N' === ZoneLetter) {
        NorthernHemisphere = 1;
    } else {
        NorthernHemisphere = 0;
        y -= 10000000.0;
    }

    var LongOrigin = (ZoneNumber - 1) * 6 - 180 + 3;

    var eccPrimeSquared = (this.eccSquared) / (1 - this.eccSquared);

    M = y / 0.9996;
    var mu = M / (this.a * (1 - this.eccSquared / 4 - 3 * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared / 64 - 5 * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared * this.eccSquared / 256));

    var phi1Rad = mu + (3 * e1 / 2 - 27 * e1 * e1 * e1 / 32) * Math.sin(2 * mu)
            + (21 * e1 * e1 / 16 - 55 * e1 * e1 * e1 * e1 / 32) * Math.sin(4 * mu)
            + (151 * e1 * e1 * e1 / 96) * Math.sin(6 * mu);
    var phi1 = this.toDegrees(phi1Rad);

    var N1 = this.a / Math.sqrt(1 - this.eccSquared * Math.sin(phi1Rad) * Math.sin(phi1Rad));
    var T1 = Math.tan(phi1Rad) * Math.tan(phi1Rad);
    var C1 = eccPrimeSquared * Math.cos(phi1Rad) * Math.cos(phi1Rad);
    var R1 = this.a * (1 - this.eccSquared) / Math.pow(1 - this.eccSquared * Math.sin(phi1Rad) * Math.sin(phi1Rad), 1.5);
    var D = x / (N1 * 0.9996);

    var Lat = phi1Rad - (N1 * Math.tan(phi1Rad) / R1) * (D * D / 2 - (5 + 3 * T1 + 10 * C1 - 4 * C1 * C1 - 9 * eccPrimeSquared) * D * D * D * D / 24
            + (61 + 90 * T1 + 298 * C1 + 45 * T1 * T1 - 252 * eccPrimeSquared - 3 * C1 * C1) * D * D * D * D * D * D / 720);
    Lat = this.toDegrees(Lat);

    var Long = (D - (1 + 2 * T1 + C1) * D * D * D / 6 + (5 - 2 * C1 + 28 * T1 - 3 * C1 * C1 + 8 * eccPrimeSquared + 24 * T1 * T1)
            * D * D * D * D * D / 120) / Math.cos(phi1Rad);
    Long = LongOrigin + this.toDegrees(Long);
    return {lat: Lat, lng: Long};
};

UTMLatLng.prototype.getUtmLetterDesignator = function (latitude) {
    latitude = parseFloat(latitude);
    if ((84 >= latitude) && (latitude >= 72))
        return 'X';
    else if ((72 > latitude) && (latitude >= 64))
        return 'W';
    else if ((64 > latitude) && (latitude >= 56))
        return 'V';
    else if ((56 > latitude) && (latitude >= 48))
        return 'U';
    else if ((48 > latitude) && (latitude >= 40))
        return 'T';
    else if ((40 > latitude) && (latitude >= 32))
        return 'S';
    else if ((32 > latitude) && (latitude >= 24))
        return 'R';
    else if ((24 > latitude) && (latitude >= 16))
        return 'Q';
    else if ((16 > latitude) && (latitude >= 8))
        return 'P';
    else if ((8 > latitude) && (latitude >= 0))
        return 'N';
    else if ((0 > latitude) && (latitude >= -8))
        return 'M';
    else if ((-8 > latitude) && (latitude >= -16))
        return 'L';
    else if ((-16 > latitude) && (latitude >= -24))
        return 'K';
    else if ((-24 > latitude) && (latitude >= -32))
        return 'J';
    else if ((-32 > latitude) && (latitude >= -40))
        return 'H';
    else if ((-40 > latitude) && (latitude >= -48))
        return 'G';
    else if ((-48 > latitude) && (latitude >= -56))
        return 'F';
    else if ((-56 > latitude) && (latitude >= -64))
        return 'E';
    else if ((-64 > latitude) && (latitude >= -72))
        return 'D';
    else if ((-72 > latitude) && (latitude >= -80))
        return 'C';
    else
        return 'Z';

};

UTMLatLng.prototype.setEllipsoid = function (name){
    switch (name) {
        case 'Airy':
            this.a = 6377563;
            this.eccSquared = 0.00667054;
            break;
        case 'Australian National':
            this.a = 6378160;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006694542;
            break;
        case 'Bessel 1841':
            this.a = 6377397;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006674372;
            break;
        case 'Bessel 1841 Nambia':
            this.a = 6377484;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006674372;
            break;
        case 'Clarke 1866':
            this.a = 6378206;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006768658;
            break;
        case 'Clarke 1880':
            this.a = 6378249;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006803511;
            break;
        case 'Everest':
            this.a = 6377276;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006637847;
            break;
        case 'Fischer 1960 Mercury':
            this.a = 6378166;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006693422;
            break;
        case 'Fischer 1968':
            this.a = 6378150;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006693422;
            break;
        case 'GRS 1967':
            this.a = 6378160;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006694605;
            break;
        case 'GRS 1980':
            this.a = 6378137;
            this.eccSquared = 0.00669438;
            break;
        case 'Helmert 1906':
            this.a = 6378200;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006693422;
            break;
        case 'Hough':
            this.a = 6378270;
            this.eccSquared = 0.00672267;
            break;
        case 'International':
            this.a = 6378388;
            this.eccSquared = 0.00672267;
            break;
        case 'Krassovsky':
            this.a = 6378245;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006693422;
            break;
        case 'Modified Airy':
            this.a = 6377340;
            this.eccSquared = 0.00667054;
            break;
        case 'Modified Everest':
            this.a = 6377304;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006637847;
            break;
        case 'Modified Fischer 1960':
            this.a = 6378155;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006693422;
            break;
        case 'South American 1969':
            this.a = 6378160;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006694542;
            break;
        case 'WGS 60':
            this.a = 6378165;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006693422;
            break;
        case 'WGS 66':
            this.a = 6378145;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006694542;
            break;
        case 'WGS 72':
            this.a = 6378135;
            this.eccSquared = 0.006694318;
            break;
        case 'ED50':
            this.a = 6378388;
            this.eccSquared = 0.00672267;
            break; // International Ellipsoid
        case 'WGS 84':
        case 'EUREF89': // Max deviation from WGS 84 is 40 cm/km see http://ocq.dk/euref89 (in danish)
        case 'ETRS89': // Same as EUREF89
            this.a = 6378137;
            this.eccSquared = 0.00669438;
            break;
        default:
            this.status = true;
            //   new Error('No ecclipsoid data associated with unknown datum: '.name);

    }
};

UTMLatLng.prototype.toDegrees = function (rad) {

    return rad / Math.PI * 180;
};

UTMLatLng.prototype.toRadians = function (deg) {

    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
};

function precisionRound(number, precision) {
      var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
      return Math.round(number * factor) / factor;
  }
  
/*********************/
/** end copied from https://github.com/shahid28/utm-latlng/blob/master/UTMLatLngFront.js **/
/*********************/
/*********************/
/*********************/
  

const utm = new UTMLatLng();
const result = utm.convertLatLngToUtm(44.062027, 143.5279742, 1);
console.log(result);
document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```